# jbpm maven build failing

Tags: maven, jbpm, kie

I have cloned one jbpm git repository in eclipse and imported the project.
When i convert the same to a maven project, build is failing

Error

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:6.1.0.Final or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:jar:6.1.0.Final ()    pom.xml /jBpmLearn  line 1  Maven pom Loading Problem

How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which project you are cloning or why it's failing exactly, but have you added the JBoss Nexus maven repo so it knows where to find all the jBPM artefacts, like:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/pom.xml#L50